# Performance cost of Java dynamic proxy

Tags: java, performance, aop, dynamic-proxy

Many modern frameworks (Spring, Hibernate) provide very nice dynamic behaviors with use of Java dynamic proxies, but what's the exact performance cost associated with it? Are there public benchmarks available for Sun JVM?

Answer (score 44, accepted):

A few pointers:

- [Debunking myths: proxies impact performance](http://blog.springsource.com/2007/07/19/debunking-myths-proxies-impact-performance/) (have a look at the comments too)
- [Java theory and practice: Decorating with dynamic proxies](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-jtp08305.html)
- [Benchmarking the cost of dynamic proxies](http://ordinaryjava.blogspot.com/2008/08/benchmarking-cost-of-dynamic-proxies.html)

Comment: Thanks for the links, especially for the last one that provides the real benchmark number: factor of 1.63 in raw use

Answer (score 8):

I don't know if there is any performance analysis in the framework you mentioned, but in my project [lambdaj](http://code.google.com/p/lambdaj/) I made a very large use of dynamic proxy using the same technology (cglib). In the pdf that explains how my library works you can also find an interesting performance comparison on this subject.

Comment: If I got it right your framework slows the iterations by average factor of 4.56, but would you relate it to the cglib proxies or to other elements of the library?

Comment: The 2 things that mostly slow down the performance of lambdaj are cglib and reflection. My measurements shows that the second is just a bit more relevant than the first. So I suppose that roughly an invocation through cglib can be considered about twice slower than a normal one.

Answer (score 2):

According to Remi Forax, java proxy forbid the Jit compiler to do correctly his job (inlining in this case).

See his rewrote of Proxy

https://github.com/forax/proxy2