# Is there an elegant way to make every method in a class start with a certain block of code in C#?

Tags: c#

I have a class where every method starts the same way:

```
internal class Foo {
  public void Bar() {
    if (!FooIsEnabled) return;
    //...
  }
  public void Baz() {
    if (!FooIsEnabled) return;
    //...
  }
  public void Bat() {
    if (!FooIsEnabled) return;
    //...
  }
}
```

Is there a nice way to require (and hopefully not write each time) the `FooIsEnabled` part for every public method in the class?

I check [Is there an elegant way to make every method in a class start with a certain block of code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31121513/is-there-an-elegant-way-to-make-every-method-in-a-class-start-with-a-certain-blo?newsletter=1&nlcode=459283%7c5be2), but that question is for Java, and its answer are using Java Library.

Comment: You could use something like DynamicProxy to weave this in at runtime.

Comment: The answer is pretty much the same as the Java one - aspect oriented programming (e.g. PostSharp) or dynamic proxies. Or of course, code generation - just make a simple T4 template to generate the proxy at compile-time.

Comment: There is even Fody as an alternative... modifying the assembly after compilation. Note that .NET doesn't have an in-language `java.lang.reflect.Proxy`

Comment: Now more importantly why are you doing this and in which kind of solution? There could be builtin solutions in the platform you are using.

Comment: You might want to consider a polymorphic solution. Extract a common interface and provide two implementations: one (`Foo`) that executes code in functions, and the other (`FooDisabled`) which simply provides dummy method implementations without a body. You can then instantiate the one you need in your specific case.

Comment: AOP but it may be pretty overkill if you start to use it just for this. A good old private member with a descriptive name...seems helpful and elegant enough (to me). Of course a base class and abstract implementation methods may also hide this in a class hierarchy but I've do it only if and when *required*

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The principal your are looking for is Interception from the domain of [Aspect Oriented Programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aspect-oriented_programming) or AOP.

While C# does not directly support it, there are solid choices:

1. [Postsharp](http://doc.postsharp.net/method-interception)
2. [Unity Interception](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn178466(v=pandp.30).aspx)
3. [Spring.NET](http://www.springframework.net/doc-latest/reference/html/aop.html)
4. [Castle Interceptors](https://github.com/castleproject/Windsor/blob/master/docs/registering-interceptors-and-proxyoptions.md)

If I get time tomorrow, I will cook up an example for you...

Comment: Don`t forget [Castle Interceptors](https://github.com/castleproject/Windsor/blob/master/docs/interceptors.md)

Answer (score 4):

I don't think you can easily get rid of the extra clutter in the Bar, Baz, Bat methods, but you can make it more manageable with creating a method to execute action you are passing in as such.

```
internal class Foo
{
    private bool FooIsEnabled;

    public void Bar()
    {
        Execute(() => Debug.WriteLine("Bar"));
    }

    public void Baz()
    {
        Execute(() => Debug.WriteLine("Baz"));
    }

    public void Bat()
    {
        Execute(() => Debug.WriteLine("Bat"));
    }

    public void Execute(Action operation)
    {
        if (operation == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("operation");

        if (!FooIsEnabled)
            return;

        operation.Invoke();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Sure:

```
internal interface IFoo {
    void Bar();
    void Baz();
    void Bat();
}

internal class Foo {
    private IFoo FooImplementation = new DisabledFoo() // or new EnabledFoor()

    public bool FooIsEnabled
    {
        get
        {
            return FooImplementation is EnabledFoo;
        }
        set
        {
            FooImplementation = value ? new EnabledFoo() : new DisabledFoo()
        }
    }

    public void Bar() {
        FooImplementation.Bar();
    }
    public void Baz() {
        FooImplementation.Baz();
    }
    public void Bat() {
        FooImplementation.Bat();        
    }
}

internal class EnabledFoo : IFoo {
    public void Bar() {
        //...
    }
    public void Baz() {
        //...
    }
    public void Bat() {
        //...
    }
}

internal class DisabledFoo : IFoo {
    public void Bar() {}
    public void Baz() {}
    public void Bat() {}
}
```

And if your intent is to mock the foo implementation for unit testing, just drop the `FooIsEnabled` property and make `FooImplementation` public.  In this case you should also get rid of `DisabledFoo`, and test using an instance such as:

```
var fooImplementationMock = new Mock<IFoo>();
var foo = new Foo { FooImplementation = fooImplementationMock.Object };
foo.Bar();
fooImplementationMock.Verify(f => f.Bar());
```

given you are using `moq`.